# What is the practice on committing firebase files in a NodeJS app?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, repository, gitignore

I've recently explored [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) for hosting a React app in a NodeJS environment. Initializing the firebase CLI tools created two files:

```
.firebaserc
firebase.json
```

**What is the accepted practice for committing these files to the repository?** No? I searched Google, and ironically diddn't find what I was looking for.

---

I work on two machines, and feel like `.firebaserc` is environment/machine specific, and thus should not be committed to the repository. If I were working on this project with other developers, I have a feeling that I would want `firebase.json` to be consistent between environments/machines. I would not want another developer making changes to `firebase.json` independent of others working on the codebase.

Thus, I am thinking commit `firebase.json` and adding `.firebaserc` to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You should always check in `firebase.json`.

For shared team projects (where you're generally working with the same projects for staging, prod, etc) you **would** check in `.firebaserc`. For open-source samples or other codebases where you would not expect everyone to be working with the same projects, you **would not** check in `.firebaserc`.

The only time this gets to be a gray area is when a team wants to have per-developer dev/test projects. Here my guidance would be still to check in the `.firebaserc` with proper staging/prod/etc. aliases and have each developer just run `firebase use my-personal-test-project` for individual test environments.

Comment: The CLI docs also address .firebaserc: "In general, you should check your .firebaserc project into source control [...] Open source projects or starter templates should generally not check in the .firebaserc file." 
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#source_control_and_project_aliases

Comment: What advice do you have for when different team members need to have different ports running in the emulator? I don't see any way to change the ports except in firebase.json, which is a shared file.